# how do I reload a module ONLY if it was NOT just loaded by the currently executing script

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I've got a script I'm using to initialize and train a neural network with Keras, so I've initialized random seeds for 100% reproducible training results as I test and optimize my code.  Meanwhile, I also have been using the importlib.reload() function to reload all my custom modules that I'm changing as I develop.  But the problem is that my random sequence may be different the FIRST time I call the script in an ipython session, vs. the subsequent times.  I found a solution (see below), but it seems pretty inelegant and heavy-handed.  I'm wondering if there's a more efficient, or more pythonic way.  Or perhaps I should handle the random seeds differently altogether?

```
import sys
modulesUnderDevelopment = ['common_config', 'cnn_tools', 'prep_dataset'] 
moduleShorthand = ['cc', 'ct', 'pd']
reloadTracker = dict()
#record which modules have not yet been imported, before we do any importing.  
for moduleName, shorthand in zip(modulesUnderDevelopment, moduleShorthand):
    reloadTracker[moduleName] = {'imported':moduleName in sys.modules, 'shorthand': shorthand}

#import modules.  Anything that's already been imported won't be imported by these lines,
# so any randomness that occurs during import will NOT occur if the module was 
# already imported.  HOWEVER, if the module has not been imported, any randomness 
# in the module import will be executed.
print('imports are beginning')
import common_config as cc
import cnn_tools as ct
import prep_dataset as pd
print('imports are ending')

import importlib
#now reload the key modules that I'm optimizing and regularly changing.  These reloads will
# ALWAYS happen, so the randomness in them will always be executed.  
print('reloads are beginning')
for key, item in reloadTracker.items():
    if not item['imported']:
        continue
    if key == 'common_config':
        importlib.reload(cc)
    elif key == 'cnn_tools':
        importlib.reload(ct)
    elif key == 'prep_dataset':
        importlib.reload(pd)
print('reloads are complete')
```

Meanwhile, my modules contain code like this:

```
## prep_dataset ##
import numpy as np
print('starting prep_dataset -- {}'.format(np.random.random()))

## cnn_tools ##
import numpy as np
print('starting cnn_tools -- {}'.format(np.random.random()))
```

The FIRST time I start ipython and run this script, it prints this:

```
imports are beginning
starting cnn_tools -- 0.5507979025745755
Using TensorFlow backend.
starting prep_dataset -- 0.7081478226181048
imports are ending
reloads are beginning
reloads are complete
```

Subsequent times, it prints this:

```
imports are beginning
imports are ending
reloads are beginning
starting cnn_tools -- 0.5507979025745755
starting prep_dataset -- 0.7081478226181048
reloads are complete
```

So that solves my problem - the random number stream is the same both times.  But it seems really clumsy...  Conversely, if i don't go through all this trouble and just import followed by reload, i get a DIFFERENT result the first time I run the script - 2 extra random numbers from the stream.

```
starting cnn_tools -- 0.5507979025745755
Using TensorFlow backend.
starting prep_dataset -- 0.7081478226181048
reloads are beginning
starting cnn_tools -- 0.2909047389129443
starting prep_dataset -- 0.510827605197663
reloads are complete
```